# Как я могу запросить определенные данные с сервера, используя UDP?

Tags: c++, windows, udp, winsock

Меня интересует, как правильно запрашивать данные через клиента. Например, сервер имеет два типа данных. Я хотел бы попросить данные под буквой а
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    Client                           Server
       |                               |
       |                               |         for example an array
       |                               |     a - data (1,2,3,4,5)
       |          how to ask?          |    /
    sendto - - - - - - a - - - - -> recvfrom  
       |                               |    \
       |                               |     b - data (0,0,0,2,1)
       |                               |
       |                               |
   recvfrom <- - - - - a - - - - - - sendto
       |
       |
       |
       a (1,2,3,4,5)
```

На данный момент я отправляю данные и получаю вот так

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>


amountRead = recvfrom(sock, (char*)&array_a, sizeof array_a, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&sAddr, &sizeAddr);
if (amountRead == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cout << " WARNING: " << "\t" << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << " GOOD: " << "\t" << std::endl;
}

sendto(sock, (char*)&array_a, sizeof array_a, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&sAddr, sizeAddr);
```

Как вы понимаете, сейчас нет вторых данных, все потому, что я не знаю, как выполнить проверку на сервере по запросу клиента, а также не знаю, что клиент должен отправить на сервер, чтобы получить определенные данные.

Comment: Используйте любой заранее оговоренный формат сообщения для этих запросов. В чём проблема?

Comment: @вася оговоренный, это типа отправлять первые данные как идентификатор
или как то можно идентифицировать данные после получения?
Я сейчас отсылаю массив array и получаю этот массив, потом отсылаю его обратно что получил.

Comment: Как лучше подходит к вашей ситуации. Можно, например, выделить первый бит сообщения под "является ли это сообщение запросом на тип данных", если он выставлен в 1, то второй бит будет означать тип `a` или `b`, а для не запроса это будут полезные данные. На стороне сервера парсить эти сообщения. Можно отдельно посылать сообщение с запросом определённого вида.

Comment: @вася а как это выглядит именно проверка первых бит, можете показать, это типа просто `if else` или как то по другому?

Comment: я сейчас использую локальную сеть для соединения сервера и клиента поэтому ip `127.0.0.1` порт могу любой ставить, в данный момент `5001`

Comment: Да, обычный `if`.

Comment: @вася а это единственный способ проверки, или есть еще какие то?

Comment: Ну на уровне UDP только вручную проверять полученные датаграммы, ничего встроенного типа "тип датаграммы" нет.

Comment: @вася понял спасибо, а если я буду отсылать пустые данные, можно как то эффективно заставить сервер отправить ответ.
Или он все равно должен посмотреть что получил для принятие решение?

Так сказать молниеносный ответ если пакет пуст.

Comment: Какая-то проверка в итоге должна быть. Хотя бы на длину сообщения.

Comment: @вася в принципе я теперь понимаю как все реализовать, конечно я надеялся что в сокетах есть специальные функции, но раз их нету буду через пакеты с данными проверять. Спасибо.

Answer (score -3):

Используйте любой заранее оговоренный формат сообщения для этих запросов. Можно, например, выделить первый бит сообщения под "является ли это сообщение запросом на тип данных", если он выставлен в 1, то второй бит будет означать тип a или b, а для не запроса это будут полезные данные. На стороне сервера парсить эти сообщения. Можно отдельно посылать сообщение с запросом определённого вида.

Comment: Если копипастите комменты в ответ, то хотя бы указывайте источник, а то получается плагиат.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat почитайте про лицензии на комментарии и ответы на мете, никакого плагиата нет, любой может копировать ответы, вопросы, комментарии со стековерфлова и использовать их даже в коммерческих целях.

Comment: Лицензия - [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). Да, все это можно, но только с указанием авторства. Но даже если бы лицензия была другая - это все равно некрасиво.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4670/ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in any reasonable matter = нет легальных обязательств, упоминайте как вам нравится. Иначе бы большую часть программистов уже пересажали бы :)

Comment: @AK Первая ссылка предлагает дополнять коммент до нормального ответа, а не просто копипастить. Вторая предлагает помечать ответ как общий (community wiki), что тоже не было сделано.

Comment: @AK Задал вопрос на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10628/215103

Comment: @joker То, что вы процитировали - это краткое объяснение лицензии, которое никакой силы не имеет...